# Display 0 where condition doesnt match

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to write a query where I need to display 0 where source system havent sent any data for today, if I write simple query with `count(*)` it provides me no rows. I am using case statement but not successful to display actual count.

```
select SRC_SYS, 
case 
when ( select count (*) from table1 where SRC_SYS ='A')='0' then '0' 
else count(1) end as Count
```

This is working fine when there is no data, but when I have data its not displaying the actual count

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

> when I have data its not displaying actual count

Er.. No, indeed it won't; it will display "1" because there is only one row; the dataset you're `count(1)`ing has only one row

Just do the count from the actual table; it'll work fine whether there are 0 rows or more because the select list only contains constants or aggregates:

```
select 'A' as SRC_SYS, COUNT(*) 
from table1 
where SRC_SYS ='A'
```

Or if your front end is using parameters:

```
select @pwhatever as SRC_SYS, COUNT(*) 
from table1 
where SRC_SYS = @pwhatever
```

See [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rhZ3qYEFbpsGkiBADRX75A/0) and change the `where 1=0` to `where 1=1` to see the count change

Comment: ok understood, by what if I have multiple source systems and want to display relevant data like below

SRC_SYS    Count
A                500
B                0
C                120

Comment: Then you should really ask a new question; SO is not a place where you ask one question, get an answer, then move the goalposts and get an edited answer, then move the goalposts again. Ask your whole question up front please. `SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN src_sys = 'A' THEN 1 END) as A, COUNT(CASE WHEN src_sys = 'B' THEN 1 END) as B, ... FROM t`